# Trouble deleting NaN in input field

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, selenium-webdriver-c#

I'm using Selenium to fill in a web form. The fields there have their default values, usually it's `0`. If I issue the command

```
Driver.chrome.FindElement(By.Id("ID_of_my_element")).Clear();
```

the value changes from `0` to `NaN`. The following input

```
Driver.chrome.FindElement(By.Id("ID_of_my_element")).SendKeys("12345");
```

results in `NaN12345`. The desired result should be `12345`.

This the HTML of the said field:

```
<input class="form-control two-decimals text-box single-line" 
data-val="true" data-val-number="The field myField must be a number." 
data-val-required="The myField field is required." id="myId" 
name="myName" style="max-width:100%; width:500px;" type="text" value="0.00">
```

Is there a way for me to fill these fields since my usual `.Clear()` and then `SendKeys()` route isn't giving me the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may want to use the javascript executor to get around the validation modifying the value inside the field between the Clear and SendKeys actions.

```
IWebElement field = driver.FindElement(By.Id("myId"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '12345')", field);
```

Syntax not guaranteed on this, as I don't have a C# environment set up.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a delay between the calls to Clear and SendKeys, then this could explain your problem.

Then again, you may just have to do something like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249583/selenium-webdriver-i-want-to-overwrite-value-in-field-instead-of-appending-to-i

I suspect that anonygoose gives a correct answer, but just like him, I cannot test to see for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I solved using this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id(element)).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
driver.FindElement(By.Id(element)).SendKeys(value);
```

It selects all the text in the first line, and then overwrites with the second.